# Impala 1.2.1 ERROR: Couldn't open transport for localhost:26000(connect() failed: Connection refused)

Tags: cloudera, impala

Using impala-shell, I can see the hive metastore, use any data base created by Hive and query any table created by Hive. When I try to create a table in impala-shell or do a "invalidate metadata", I get

"ERROR: Couldn't open transport for localhost:26000(connect() failed: Connection refused)"

Have following configuration. This is a multi-node cluster configuration *** built by hand i.e. without using Cloudera Manager ***

- CentOS 6
- CDH4.5
- Impala 1.2.1
- Hive MySQL Metastore
- impalad are running on multiple nodes with data nodes
- statestored and catalogd is running on a single node that is NOT impalad node
- In /etc/default/impala I have changed IMPALA_STATE_STORE_HOST to point to IP of the statestored machine
- From the /var/log/impala/catalogd.INFO, it seems 26000 is used by catalog service as there is a line in this file "--catalog_service_port=26000"

Just as /etc/default/impala has to tell Impalad where is the statestore (using IMPALA_STATE_STORE_HOST), I am wondering if for 1.2.1 (where catalogd is introduced) there has to be an additional entry for catalogd location as well - just a guess ....

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Please note this was also posted on Google group and was answered there. See https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/impala-user/gKVHQBmGA2c

Answer (score 1):

you have to start the impalad with the option `-catalog_service_host=fqdn_to_your_catalog_host`.

unfortunately this is not yet in the default configuration so you have to add it yourself

change /etc/default/impala

- `CATALOG_SERVICE_HOST=fqdn_to_your_catalog_host`
- `IMPALA_SERVER_ARGS=`add: `-catalog_service_host=${CATALOG_SERVICE_HOST}`

restart impalad and it should work now :-)

Comment: Sorry to reopen the question two years later, but where did you get this information ? Do you have any documentation mentionning this solution ? I'm facing the same problem and couldn't find any solution till now